# Array loop does not show subsequent values

Tags: arrays, c#-4.0

I have a C# WinForms application, which uses a StringBuilder to append values for the month, dayOfWeek, time of day, name, date, and optional comment.

Each value is following by appending a comma and then the next value. I create a string[] array string[] thisAssignment, after which I assign the StringBuilder to the array as follows:

thisAssignment = fsAssign.ToString().Split(',');
RecordMonday2SaturdayAssignments(thisAssignment);

I pass the array to a method, where I assign the individual elements of the array to variables and then parameterize them for a SQL INSERT statement.

The problem I've encountered is that when stepping through the code I can see the month and dayOfWeek i.e., "Monday". However, upon the next iteration, it again shows the Monday value instead of moving on to Tuesday, etc.

I show the loop below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < assignments.Length; i++ )
{
    month = assignments[0].ToString();
    dayOfWeek = assignments[1].ToString();
    fsTimes = assignments[2].ToString();
    name = assignments[3].ToString();
    date = assignments[4].ToString();
    comment = assignments[5].ToString();

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    List<SqlParameter> list = new List<SqlParameter>();
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@month", month));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@dayOfWeek", dayOfWeek));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@fsTimes", fsTimes));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@names", name));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@dates", date));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@comments", comment));
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(list.ToArray<SqlParameter>());
    int response = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I have also tried adding the index before or after the element number of the array as shown below

```
for (int i = 0; i < assignments.Length; i++ )
{
    month = assignments[i][0].ToString();
    dayOfWeek = assignments[i][1].ToString();
    fsTimes = assignments[i][2].ToString();
    name = assignments[i][3].ToString();
    date = assignments[i][4].ToString();
    comment = assignments[i][5].ToString();
}
```

However, instead of showing the correct values, the loop pulled a single character from the name of the month. For example, when I selected the month of February, the month variable was populated with the letter "F", the dayOfWeek variable had an "e", fsTimes had a "b" and so on. In my original post I neglected to mention that I HAD used the "i" index along with the array element.

If someone has a helpful suggestion on forming the array loop differently, I would love to hear it. Or even better, to SEE a suggestion that will allow me to pull multiple values from the array and assign them to the aforementioned variables.

Comment: Since you never use `i`, the variable that you modify with the loop construct, within the loop at all: why do you expect different behavior on each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

I've kept trying various ideas for solving this problem and finally discovered what works in this situation. Since just using the individual indexes only provided data on the first iteration, and using "i" by itself returned individual characters, I discovered that incrementing "i += 1" from the second element on returned my data from all the rows.

I show what I've done below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < assignments.Count; i++)
{
    month = assignments[i];
    dayOfWeek = assignments[i += 1];
    fsTimes = assignments[i += 1];
    name = assignments[i += 1];
    date = assignments[i += 1];
    comment = assignments[i += 1];

    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

    List<SqlParameter> list = new List<SqlParameter>();
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@month", month));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@dayOfWeek", dayOfWeek));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@fsTimes", fsTimes));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@names", name));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@dates", date));
    list.Add(new SqlParameter("@comments", comment));

    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(list.ToArray<SqlParameter>());

    int response = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```